# EMMET для SUBLIME TEXT3

Tags: sublime-text-3, emmet

Всем привет. Начал изучать плагин Emmet для ST3. Очень много читаю про правило с `^`, но никак не могу понять, что оно значит, объясните кто нибудь простым языком, пожалуйста.

Пример: `div>p>span^a`.

Comment: не могли бы отметить правильный ответ ?

Answer (score 1):

Поместить выше (в дереве HTML):
Пример:

```
<!-- div>p>span+em^bq -->
<div>
    <p><span></span><em></em></p>
    <blockquote></blockquote>
</div>

<!-- div>p>span+em^^bq -->
<div>
    <p><span></span><em></em></p>
</div>
<blockquote></blockquote>
```

P.S. взято с https://dwstroy.ru/stail/plaginy-rasshireniya/emmet-shpargalka/

Если взять ваш пример `div>p>span^a` то это будет выглядеть так

```
<div>
    <p><span></span></p>
    <a></a>
</div>
```

На пальцах это "**div**, в **div** **p**, в **p** **span** И **a** (но **a** вынесу на уровень выше)"

Answer (score 1):

^a создает элемент a, только на одну позицию выше.